# Stuck in "verifying database integrity"

Tags: database

I restarted my computer and now bitcoin doesnt go further than "verifying database integrity" and staying in until now (about an hour now) also windows tells me that the program isnt responding.

Anyone knows what to do ?

Comment: StackExchange Q&A isn't a very good place for providing tech support.  The BitcoinTalk forum has a Technical Support board that works well in getting this types of problems resolved.

Comment: Your debug.log will likely give more info about what the problem is.